# Stop USB Printer From Switching to "Use Offline"

Tags: windows-10, usb, printing, printer

I have a user who has a USB-attached printer.

Sometimes he forgets to turn it on, and starts printing things. After his queue has about 100 copies of the same thing, he will give up, and try another day. Other times he will forget to open the paper tray, or something else that prevents printing.

The next day he tries to print something else, remembers to turn it on, and is faced with 100 prints of whatever he tried to print yesterday.

I have a partial solution to this. I have a VBScript that will empty the print queue. This works just fine, as long as the printer doesn't enable it's offline use.

If "use offline" gets enabled I need to disable it.
I haven't found a good solution to this yet.

Is there any way I can completely disable offline usage?
I would be OK with a script that toggles this off, but I'd prefer some way to never allow offline usage.

Comment: Might be important to know the make/model of printer.

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach. You need to educate the user or put a sign on the computer "please turn on printer before attempting to print". It sounds like no matter what you do this person will find some way to mess it up.

Comment: @ZiggyStardust The user is 95 and uses said printer because he is unable to write due to a stroke. Unfortunately I've already exhausted the avenue you are suggesting.